# Ponteiro muda de endereço ao sair de função

Tags: c, ponteiro, array, alocação

Ao realizar uma alocação dinâmica de um vetor ou matriz em C, o ponteiro referente a essa alocação muda de endereço ao sair da função, sendo que antes ele estava apontando para o endereço inicial da área alocada e logo após o término da respectiva função ele aponta para o endereço 1. Como mostrado a seguir, o ponteiro é passado como parâmetro pela função para efetuar a manipulação posterior dos dados alocados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void aloca(int *vetorInt, int tamanho);

int main (void) {
    int *vetor;

    aloca(vetor, 2);
    printf("END. NA MAIN: %d", vetor);
}

void aloca(int *vetorInt, int tamanho) {
    //Inicializa o ponteiro com NULL para nao ter problema
    vetorInt = NULL;
    //Aloca n espaços
    vetorInt = (int *) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));

    //Verifica se foi alocado e exibe o endereço para qual o ponteiro aponta
    if (vetorInt != NULL) {
        printf("*** VETOR ALOCADO.\nENDERECO NA FUNCAO: %d ***\n", vetorInt);
        getchar();
    } else {
        printf("*** NAO ALOCADO ***\n");
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Ao rodar o código verifico que o endereço foi alterado e no fim perco o acesso a esse vetor, não podendo realizar a desalocação de memória ou manipulação de dados. Por que isso acontece? Qual a solução?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse é um problema clássico em C. O que ocorre é que o ponteiro `vetorInt` é local ao escopo da função `aloca` (da mesma forma que o inteiro `tamanho` também é). Você modifica o valor dele dentro da função, mas o mesmo é perdido ao sair dela, pois a variável `vetorInt` deixa de existir.

Existem duas formas de solucionar isso:

- Faça a função devolver o endereço alocado, e faça `vetor` recebê-lo no `main`.
- Mude o parâmetro da variável na função para um ponteiro de ponteiro: `int **vetorInt`. Assim é necessário passar o endereço do ponteiro no `main` (`&vetor`). Dentro da função, também é necessário se referir à variável como `*vetorInt`. Como pode ver, este método é um pouco mais confuso, principalmente para iniciantes.

Comment: As duas soluções realmente são bem funcionais, embora a segunda seja mais complexa por levar em consideração indireção múltipla, que muitas pessoas não compreendem bem, logo a primeira solução se torna mais prática pra um propósito mais geral. Grato!

Answer (score 4):

Idealmente é melhor alocar no lugar que vai usar, assim fica mais fácil rastrear o que precisa liberar, mas se quiser fazer assim mesmo o mais adequado é retornar o ponteiro e não passar como parâmetro, que complica a sintaxe. Tirei o que era desnecessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *aloca(int *vetorInt, int tamanho) {
    vetorInt = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));
    if (vetorInt != NULL) printf("*** VETOR ALOCADO.\nENDERECO NA FUNCAO: %d ***\n", vetorInt);
    else printf("*** NAO ALOCADO ***\n");
    return vetorInt;
}

int main (void) {
    int *vetor = aloca(vetor, 2);
    printf("END. NA MAIN: %d", vetor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fnfKnu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ildmacej-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Vector.c).

Comment: Realmente o ideal é alocar no escopo em que for utilizado, porém a função com a qual estou lidando é bem mais complexa e irei utilizá-la várias vezes ao longo do software, por isso passei para uma função para não precisar reescrevê-la várias vezes. Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: Alias C tem uma função chamada `aloca()` está pedindo para ter problemas :)